# Get the latest subscription response from array of observables - Angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs

**Function**: I have multiple `POST` requests to update a single table with different data. The response from the request will contain the updated table data.

I pushed the `observables` into an **array** and used `forkJoin` to get the results from all the `POST` requests.

However only the latest received response is needed to update my view. I assumed that `forkJoin` will return responses array in an order of `POST` responses.

**Sample code**:

```js
getResponse ( inpDataArray: []) {
    let observableList: Observable<any>[] = [],
    HTTP_OPTIONS = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    };

    inpDataArray.forEach(eachData => {
      observableList.push(
        this.httpClient.post('<SERVERURL>', eachData, HTTP_OPTIONS)
      ); // PUSH
    }); // FOR-EACH

    forkJoin(observableList).subscribe( (allResponseData: []) => {
      allResponseData.forEach( (eachResult, index) => {
        console.log('Result #', index, ' , length: ', eachResult.length );
      }); // FOR-EACH
    }); // FORK-JOIN
  } // FN

this.getResponse([
  {type:1, value:'data1'},
  {type:2, value:'data2'}
]);

// Response will contain the list of all the inputs sent as POST request - as an array of objects
```

**Result**:
Randomly I'm seeing the last element of the response array is NOT the response from the latest `POST` request.

```
// Sample response
Result #1, length: 1
Result #2, length: 2


// Sample response
Result #1, length: 4
Result #2, length: 3
```

Could someone help me explain what I'm doing wrong?

**Tried options**:
I tried few other RxJS methods but with my understanding of `race` and `forkJoin`, my code should have worked.

As I'm into Angular for only few days and trying to push this req within a day, so couldn't find time to read the docs end-to-end.

**Temporary fix**:
I used the basic logic to find the response with highest number of elements to figure out the latest data from the server (as all my requests are adding new data-row only).

Comment: Your temporary fix is probably the correct one: all the requests are sent in parallel, and you can't expect the response from the last update handled by the server to come back after all the other ones. A better fix would be to improve your backend API in order to be able to send a single request with all the updates.

Comment: Let me ask if I got the question right, so you want to create `n` (where `n` is a number of requests) post request and you care only about the response from the latest post request, that you send, without caring about the responses from the previous ones?

Comment: @ХристиянХристов that's right.
Does any of Observable methods provide an option to sort the response?

Comment: Can you tell us how do you build the `inpDataArray`, because if we trust the `rxjs` docs you should not face the problem `Randomly I'm seeing the last element of the response array is NOT the response from the latest POST request.`

Comment: @ХристиянХристов I have edited the question with sample input and two trials of sample response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it would be better to change your API so that it could take an ordered array of data and return only the latest update. That would optimize for speed since you'd have less information traveling in the network.

But if you just want a quick fix then, you can remove the last element of `inpDataArray` and store it in a variable 'lasInpData'.

```
lasInpDataObs = this.httpClient.post('<SERVERURL>', lasInpData, HTTP_OPTIONS);
merge(observableList).concat(lasInpDataObs).last().subscribe(res => consle.log(res));
```

This ensures that you complete all other requests before going for the last one. 'Concat' only subscribes the next when previous is completed. 'last' operator filters out all the results but the last one.

Comment: I will try this method. Seems like through this way, any dynamic number of request of same type can be handled efficiently.

Comment: why would the concat part be needed at all? merge emits in order that the input observables emit. Simply taking the last one will solve it.

Comment: Only merge wouldn't work very well because after you send the requests the API might respond in a different order. We need to make sure that all previous streams completed before last stream starts.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want the last completed response, use merge:

```
merge(observableList).pipe(last());
```

merge will emit the observables in the order they emit, then you use the last operator to only take the last one.

Comment: When you call an API and send a batch of requests there is no certainty that those requests are going to be responded in the same order. That's why you should always make sure that the last request is only processed upon completion of all the others. Neither merge nor last ensure that.

Comment: OP seems pretty clear here, he doesn't want the last request in the LIST, that would be trivial... just pull the last item and request it.  He wants the last request processed, which is what merge last ensures.

Comment: Depending on the implementation, the API may be handling multiple requests in parallel, each needs to be forwarded to a database, and responses need to be collected back from the database afterwords. There is no certainty that last response returned from the API was in fact the last to be processed in the database.